# VirtualHost directing to same DocumentRoot?

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost

For some reason both domain1.org and domain2.org are both directing into /var/www is there something I missed? Apache2 error log is clean too? I just don't get it. It should be a simple vhosting

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerName domain1.org
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/

    <Directory /var/www/>
        DirectoryIndex index.php        
        Options -Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel debug

    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerName domain2.org
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/wordpress-1/

    <Directory /var/www/wordpress-1/ >
        DirectoryIndex index.php        
        Options -Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel debug

    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Do you have NameVirtualHost before these?

Comment: Depending on what version of Linux you have. I put my virtual hosts in different files under the sites-available/ folder in the apache2 dir, and I have to enable them with a2ensite before they will work. Maybe this has to apply to you?

Comment: I realize now that I get **[Sun Oct 02 06:26:32 2011] [error] [client 69.41.186.114] Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.** as an error in my apache error log? This is followed by a internal server error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There doesn't appear to be anything wrong with your VirtualHost definitions. Did you remember to restart apache after updating the config file ? You don't say which OS you are using so it's difficult to progress. You should have a look at the output of

```
/usr/sbin/apache2ctl -S
```

or

```
/usr/sbin/httpd -S
```

this will show the vhirtual hoststhat your apache knows about and will also indicate if you have name-based virtual hosting enabled e.g.

```
 /usr/sbin/apache2ctl -S
VirtualHost configuration:
wildcard NameVirtualHosts and _default_ servers:
*:80                   is a NameVirtualHost
         default server test1.lan (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default:1)
         port 80 namevhost test1.lan (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default:1)
         port 80 namevhost centos1.lan (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default:94)
         port 80 namevhost host1.test.lan (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/subhosts:41)
         port 80 namevhost host2.test.lan (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/subhosts:49)
Syntax OK
```

If you don't have a `*:80  is a NameVirtualHost` then you will need to enable it with a

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
```

directive prior to your VirtualHost definitions.

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 11.04, apache was restarted via **$ service apache2 restart** I'm not seeing an issue with the vhost either which is the problem?

Comment: the above returns `root@li85-37:/etc/apache2/sites-enabled# /usr/sbin/apache2ctl -S
VirtualHost configuration:
wildcard NameVirtualHosts and _default_ servers:
*:80                   is a NameVirtualHost
         default server micros.themonastery.org (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default:2)
         port 80 namevhost micros.themonastery.org (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default:2)
         port 80 namevhost www.ulc.org (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default:26)
Syntax OK
`